# Fortran. Which of the code shown below is right?

Tags: fortran

I have found out next interesting thing within Fortran. It's shown below in code sample.

I can't understand and have found nothing why the code at labels 10 and 12 works and at 11 and 13 doesn't.

```
implicit none
integer     :: i
integer     :: IA(8) = [(i, i=1,8)]
integer     :: IP

IP = 5
10  IA(IP:2) = [11, 12]     ! works
11  IA(5:2) = [11, 12]      ! doesn't work
12  print *, IA(IP:IP+1)    ! works 
13  print *, IA(IP:2)       ! doesn't work
```

What is the difference?

Comment: The statement labelled `11` is just as wrong as that labelled `10`, so what do you mean by one working and one not?  I assume that the compiler complains when asked to compile one: please show that error message and the options used when compiling (and mention which compiler).

Comment: gfortran-9: Error: Different shape for array assignment at (1) on dimension 1 (0 and 2)

Comment: But code at 10 works. IP = 5.

Comment: No it does not. It doesn't generate a compiler error because the compiler does not check the value of variables during compile. If you get rid of all the other errors, get a compiled program, the line labeled 10 would get a run time error because IA(IP:2) is not the same length as [11, 12] when IP = 5. Its just that the compiler does not catch that at compile time.

Comment: Sorry. It works. Try, please, by gfortran. if I need to print *, IA it does 1 2 3 4 11 12 7 8. In the case if I use code at label 10.

Answer (score 1):

Both versions of the statement labelled `10` and `11` are wrong.

The array section `ia(5:2)` is an array section consisting of zero elements of the array `ia`.  The array section `ia(IP:2)` (when `IP` is a variable with value `5`) is the same.

When using a literal constant in the array element subscripts your compiler knows when compiling that it can check the shape of the left- and right-hand sides match.  Your compiler here has determined that `ia(5:2)` is of shape `[0]` and `[11, 12]` is of non-comformable shape `[2]`.  It therefore reports the error.

Your compiler isn't detecting at compile time the error with non-constant subscripts in `ia(IP:2)`.  The code however violates the Fortran standard in exactly the same way.  The seemingly correct output you see is *bad* luck.

Your compiler may not be detecting the error at run-time either because of the options you have used to compile or because it doesn't (correctly) apply the test of shape.

Other compilers may well complain, such as with the message:

```
Rank 1 of constant array operand has extent 2 instead of 0
Program terminated by fatal error
Abort (core dumped)
```

With the statement

```
print *, IA(IP:2)
```

this does "work" (in an otherwise correctly formed program).  However, it suffers from exactly the same misunderstanding as before.

This print statement prints out zero array elements of `ia` in contrast to the two elements `ia(5:6)`.  Instead of "not working", the lack of obvious output is correctly printing nothing/a blank line.

In conclusion, `ia(5:2)` isn't a reference to the two elements after and including `ia(5)`.  For that you'd need `ia(5:6)`, or `ia(ip:ip+1)`.  The subscripts are both bounds, not a bound and a count.

Comment: Thank you very much. I shall try to compile with Intel FORTRAN. May be it works only with gfortran.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't tell you which options are required to enable the appropriate runtime test with gfortran, but there are others here who may.

Comment: I used only "-Wall -Wno-tabs -O3 -ffast-math -march=native -c" and it worked properly. But I was confused why ia(ip:2) realy works?

Comment: Actually I wrote a class in c++ using fortran object file to draw some pattern in bitmap. I used rgb(ips:4) = col(1:4) and it works properly.

Comment: You have broken the language standard. As a result anything at all is allowed to happen as what you have done is not described by the Fortran standard. This includes what you think is "works", or just as legitimately World War III could start. For me I get different behaviour from gfortran and Intel Fortran. Both can't be "works". Now I admit I am surprised that neither compiler detects this error, at least with the flags I tried, and am somewhat disappointed by this, but it doesn't stop what you are describing being WRONG.

Comment: Yes, @smval80, , as Ian Bush has commented, the output "1 2 3 4 11 12 7 8" _isn't_ the correct output, at least as defined by the Fortran standard.  It may be that the compiler is "being nice" and giving the output you expect, but I'd actually suggest that you contact the compiler support for Intel and GCC and request that they improve diagnostics.

Comment: @IanBush, which compiler options did you use?  And for Intel, which version?  I thought  Intel recently improved shape diagnostics so would be good to know if this case is still missed.

Comment: Thank you all. I use for Intel FORTRAN v. 2019 update 4 only "-O3" option. I'm afraid my English is too bad for discuss that problem with maintainers.

Comment: <the compiler is "being nice"> - It's funny. You made my morning good! Thanks.

Comment: From memory -fcheck=all with gfortran and -check all with Intel

Comment: Thanks, @IanBush.  That's a saddening start to the day.

Comment: It may have been an older version of ifort, will check later, but gfortran was 8.2

Comment: @IanBush, I've just tried with ifort 19.1 and there was the hoped-for runtime error.

Comment: Did you use some compiler parameters to check that error?

Comment: Ifort 19.4 -O3 generates no warnings.

Comment: @smval80, you'll need to use the `-check` option with ifort to enable runtime checks.